# Strange git behaviour reverting changes made in local branches after pulling upstream merges

Tags: git, github, dvcs, git-workflow

We have a team of around 10 developers and we are frequently running into a situation where someone's changes got reverted unexpectedly. Our workflow has been very simple. Developers make local commits, pull from upstream, and then push to upstream (this is our workflow in a nutshell, but it may also include issuing pull requests on Github from a developer's personal fork of upstream). The strange behavior is a developer makes local commits, pulls from upstream, and then finds his changes have reverted back. It's as if git is resolving conflicts with `theirs` strategy although none of us have this setting, nor are there actual merge conflicts involved. The changes are more like this:

Local commit:

```
.some_style {
-  width: 150px;
+  width: 100px;
  color: black;
}
```

After merge:

```
.some_style {
  width: 150px;
  color: black;
}
```

There are no other commits touching this section of code, and no one is manually resolving merge conflicts (which shouldn't exist anyway). After the developer completes the merge and pushes it upstream, we sometimes see a diff log on another developer's commit that appears to reverse the changes made by the first developer. Usually this revert commit appears under someone else's name, although they have not touched the file in question.

Some other developer's commit:

```
.some_style {
+  width: 150px;
-  width: 100px;
  color: black;
}
```

We have no idea how this is happening or how to recreate it. Perhaps our knowledge of git collaboration is lacking in some respect and hopefully someone can point us in the right direction.

**EDIT**
This problem seems to only affect css/scss files. I noticed that the diff headers are showing the wrong information:

```
@@ -359,10 +367,12 @@ img.badge-pic {

 #sampleProfileCover {
   float: left;
-  width: 200px;
+  width: 230px;
+  height: 150px;
   text-align: center;
   img {
     width: 200px;
+    height: 220px;
   }
 }
```

Notice that the header identifies this style as `img.badge-pic`. That style actually appears much earlier in the file. Could git be having trouble parsing css/sass?

Comment: So what is your actual question?

Comment: What could possibly lead to such behavior? We have just narrowed down the problem to css files. I will update the question.

Comment: Are you seeing the diff in git bash? What OS is everyone in the team using? I suspect crlf settings might be different between machines.

Comment: We don't have Windows machines. Either Mac or Linux. The diff shows up the same on Github.

Comment: diff uses a heuristic to detect "sections" to improve the context information for humans. It works well e.g. for C functions, but for other types it can be wrong. That said, Git does not parse file content for merging, it is purely text-based.

Comment: Could it be possible that some developers use reset without understanding its effects? Or are these files somehow automatically generated from somewhere else?

Comment: These files are Rails css assets. They are not the compiled stylesheets but the raw sass.

Comment: @robinst, or somebody is going `git rebase -i` into previously published history, and/or doing a `git push -f` "so that it works, if I don't use `-f` it complains and doesn't push". Perhaps a round of brain wash^W^Wtraining in git is required here...

Comment: We are fairly confident that no one is using rebase or using `-f`.

Comment: The fact that it occurs infrequently in your environment where conflicts are not expected, really does suggest '-f' use.  Might be worth checking shell aliases.  I don't see a git config variable like 'push.force true', understandably.

Comment: Are you all working on the same branch, ie `master`? I don't think trusting the `pull` merge is the best. Maybe switching to topic branches help you - branch, commit, checkout master, pull, merge branch, push.

Comment: We have some topic branches, but unfortunately most of the work is applied directly to `master`. You may be on to something about blindly trusting `pull`. We've been advocating for a `git fetch upstream`, `git diff ...upstream/master`, `git merge upstream/master` workflow. That way devs can see what will be applied by the merge. But it's still perplexing how merging from upstream could revert unrelated changes.

Comment: Do you guys rename files a lot?

Comment: The rename question is kind of important. If you have a bunch of css files that all look almost exactly the same, and you are constantly renaming them, and the merge strategy in git includes rename detection, you could conceivable have git apply the wrong patch to the wrong file.

Comment: No, we have not been renaming a lot. This issue is occurring in the middle of large css files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you do `git push --force` to send conflicting commits to the server. This *can* work if the writer of the other conflicting commit then immediately pulls the forced commit and merges it -- he still has his own commit attached and the pull will show the conflict on his side (no one else will notice except when doing fsck -- SOMEONE HAS TO DO the merge. Just pushing it into oblivion is not a solution and abviously git's default settings are not for the average developer! Then the conflicting commit will be pushed aside and dangle around without being attached to the tip or how you call it. You can check that by running git fsck:

```
$ git fsck
Checking object directories: 100% (256/256), done.
dangling commit 4f851a97274917a1486f81833c6e96c4b1efeabc
```

You can also prevent your developers from using `force`. Solution: add the following to your repositories config file:

```
[receive]
    denyNonFastForwards = true
```

See also http://randyfay.com/content/avoiding-git-disasters-gory-story

Comment: We're fairly confident no one has done a `git push --force` but the blog post you linked to has what I believe to be the correct explanation. "Disaster 2: Merging Without Understanding" describes exactly what is going on with out team. Lots of rapid pulling and pushing, each creating merges without checking the diff first. Now I'm careful to always do a `git fetch upstream` and `git diff ...upstream/master` before `git merge upstream/master`.

Comment: well, I really didn't assume anyone would ever merge unless checking WHAT he is merging ;-) My fault.

Comment: To be honest: I just tried that merge problem and could not figure out how to remove others changes that are not conflicting... I'm using pull, push, commit -a, rm and sometimes clean and nothing else. That's absolutely sufficient and without fast forwards I haven't encountered any problems at all yet.

Comment: Actually merging without understanding happens every time someone does `git pull upstream master` because that does a recursive merge without the developer going over the changes first.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see that using the CLI. The pull automatically merges upstream changes and immediately shows conflicts...

Answer (score 1):

In `git`, changes don't get reverted automatically; it is *very* careful not to lose anything. Check for people doing `git rebase`, `git push -f` ("so that it works" when their push doesn't work because it isn't a fast forward), or `git reset`. Any history editing is dangerous. Have them read through some of the tutorials linked at [git-scm](http://git-scm.com).

Go over your workflow, compare with the standard git workflows and suggestions (there are several around). Git is a *tool*, in the best Unix tradition: meant for expert users who know what they are doing. So it keeps out of the way, and doesn't ever try to second-guess the user. That backfires occasionally as long as they are rank newbies, but they learn soon (or give up in frustration ;-).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect this could be an editor problem; perhaps the text editor of the developer whose name is on the reverting commits is not loading the changes that have been pulled from upstream, so when he saves, commits and pushes his changes, the text editor ends up overwriting what was brought in from Git.  This is made more more plausible by the fact it's only one kind of file that's getting reverted.

Comment: Our editors reload files that are changed on disk. Also, it would require someone to commit the changes before pushing but our workflow is generally `git commit`, `git pull`, `git push`.

Comment: @ReedG.Law Is the problem limited to a single developer, or is it happening for several developers?

Comment: It's happening for several developers.

Comment: @ReedG.Law Are they using the command line or a UI on top of it?

Comment: @ReedG.Law Just curious -- are people doing `git show` and then `git log -p` before `git push`?  In general it's good to review any code in a changeset before pushing to a remote. This would also have the effect of catching the unwanted reversions before they go out.