# 'git pull --ff-only' from shared bare master showing pulled changes as deletions (git 2.1.1)

Tags: git, nfs, corruption

Using git 2.1.1 over NFS with a bare master repository.

Users are occasionally seeing an otherwise successful 'git pull --ff-only' into a repository with no outstanding or un-pushed changes of any kind (added, cached, or otherwise) will result in the local sandbox reporting *as local deletions* all the changes it should have added to the files when the pull occurred. The history is correct, as are the SHAs, but the changes it should have applied to the files are missing and are reported as edits by the local user.

While this is easy to fix, we don't understand how this can be occurring. Is there something we are doing that could cause this? Could an NFS problem be causing it, and is there some flag we can set in git that would verify the changes are being applied successfully?

Comment: note: have read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15365383/strange-git-behaviour-reverting-changes-made-in-local-branches-after-pulling-ups and it does not seem to apply

Comment: Are they seeing the issue on their currently checked out branch (which would be weird), or on some other branch (expected)? 

And why on earth are you running a beta from 2+ years ago?

Comment: yes, current checked out branch: master

Comment: what command are they typing to see the "local deletions"?

Comment: 'git status' shows modifications that correspond to the changed lines in the latest commits, and file deletions that correspond to files added in recent commits. It is as if they manually undid all the changes of the commits included in the pulled updates.

Comment: Interesting and unexpected, but nobody is going to look into a potential bug with 2+ year old beta version.  You need to reproduce with an official release, preferably something newish.

Comment: happened with 1.8.2.1 earlier this week that one user was using in case the older version was the problem

Comment: Do you have preloadIndex set to true in your config? Other than that I don't have any ideas, other than move away from NFS as it has notoriously bad performance with Git.

Comment: yes, NFS is very bad with git, but some corporate environments will not allow local storage. preloadindex was false up until yesterday, when I decided to add it to speed up NFS as I was looking into the slowness as a different issue.

Comment: finally got an update to git 2.1.1 and it happened again to one of the same users. clearly an issue with our environment, but how/what?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any suggestion other than "don't use NFS".  You might try the git devel list.